# How to get selected qTableView row values (all column)

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

How to get the all column data for the selected row of a qtableView.
For a single index like first column I can get the data. But I want all datas in an array. How to append those selected data into an array!

```
def selectRow(self):
        index = self.tableView.selectionModel().selectedIndexes()[0]
        id = int(self.tableView_AccInfo.model().data(index))
        print ("index : " + str(id))
```

For example:

```
header --> a b c d e f
row0   --> 1 2 3 4 5 6
```

I want, `data[1,2,3,4,5,6]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to get the complete rows of the selected elements then a possible solution is:

- Get the rows
- Iterate over the columns of those rows

```
rows = {index.row() for index in self.tableView.selectionModel().selectedIndexes()}
output = []
for row in rows:
    row_data = []
    for column in range(self.tableView.model().columnCount()):
        index = self.tableView.model().index(row, column)
        row_data.append(index.data())
    output.append(row_data)
print(output)
```

Comment: wow..this is what i exactly want. thank you so much.